# Accessing DOM of frame using javascript/jquery in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension, frames

I'm working on a chrome extension that extracts metadata and some text elements from webpages. I'm encountering challenges when that information is contained within a frame of the given page.

Take the following example frameset for the page I'm working with (actual frame names, title and sources changed for brevity).

```
<frameset id="fs" border="0" frameborder="no">
    <frame src="/src1" name="frame1" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" title="FrameNumber1">
    <frame src="/src2" name="frame2" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" title="FrameNumber2">
    <frame src="/src3" name="frame3" noresize="noresize" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" title="FrameNumber3">
    <frame src="/src4" name="frame4" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" title="FrameNumber4">
</frameset>
```

And, consider the following html snippet for FrameNumber3:(this is more contrived, just for the purposes of the example)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>FrameNumber3</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="heading">This is what I want</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a number of different methods, and most of them revolve around different guesses at the proper context parameter in a jquery selector.

I've tried a few dozen, but here are some examples of things I thought could actually work:

Via [Run JQuery in the context of another frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539504/run-jquery-in-the-context-of-another-frame)

```
alert($('#heading', window.parent.frames[0].document).text());
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

alert($('#heading', window.parent.frames[2].document).text());
//Tried this, because I want the 3rd frame's information
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

Via [Accessing an element in a frame using a jQuery reference to the frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358680/accessing-an-element-in-a-frame-using-a-jquery-reference-to-the-frame)

```
alert($('#heading', $('frame').get(2).contentWindow.document).text());
//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

Via other pages:

```
alert($('#heading', $('frame[title="FrameNumber3"]').document).text());
//no error but returns "undefined"

alert($('#heading', $('frame[title="FrameNumber3"]').contents()).text());
//no error but returned "undefined"
```

I don't think it's a permissions issue within the chrome extension, because I've taken care of that. I think it's likely there is something I'm not understanding about getting to the frame DOM. I've also read that jquery isn't the most reliable when it comes to frames, so I guess that could be the issue as well.

Thanks in advance for any feedback or assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665679/chrome-extension-access-to-frame-elements/18564015#18564015) will help.

```
document.querySelector('#SomeFrameSelector').contentWindow.document.body.onload
```